# Docker for windows seems to timeout when connecting to external HTTP server

Tags: asp.net, docker

I am running a .NET framework application on top of microsoft/windowsservercore. My application communicates, via HTTP, with an external server. Quick requests work well, but when the external server takes more time to reply, I get the following error:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://server/myservice.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive. ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      at System.Net.PooledStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>      at System.Net.Connection.SyncRead(HttpWebRequest request, Boolean userRetrievedStream, Boolean probeRead)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
>      at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)

When I run my application from the host machine, instead of Docker, everyting goes well.

It looks like somehow Docker times out and closes the HTTP connection to my server. Anyone faced this? How can I work around it?